# Upgrading Vue Template Loader to work with Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So In my Vue2 project I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-vue-template-loader) to not need to use a .vue file. However as can be seen in the `.d.ts`file

```
// TypeScript type module definition required for vue-template-loader
declare module '*.html' {
  import Vue, { ComponentOptions } from 'vue';

  interface WithRender {
    <V extends Vue>(options: ComponentOptions<V>): ComponentOptions<V>
    <V extends typeof Vue>(component: V): V
  }

  const withRender: WithRender
  export = withRender
}
```

This of course is not compatible with Vue3. `vue` would be imported with `import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component' in my case.

I can't seem to find anywhere anything about how I could migrate the below to work in Vue3 such that I can import the HTML file into my .ts